# indent bulleted lines in android TextView

Tags: android, indentation, spannable

Will someone please help me figure this out?

I have a TextView that is supposed to contain a number of bulleted lines. If a given line is too long, I need it to wrap indented. How do I do that?

Here is my code, which obviously isn't doing what I want (right now the text wrap without indentation)

```
String str = "";
 for (String s : linesList) {
   str += ("\u2022 \t \t" + s + "\n");
 }
textView.setText(str);
```

Imaging the following 3 lines belong to a single TextView, this is what I want (gibberish):

- This is the first line in the list, and it is going to span more than one line just so you can see that the subsequent lines are indented beyond the bullet itself. So this is what I want.
- Shorter lines are free to behaves as normal
- But all longer lines are supposed to follow the exact same indentation rules: that is, they should wrap with indentation. If you computer screen is so wide that you cannot see what I am talking about, please reduce it to the size of a laptop so you can see the indentation. Thank you.

Comment: The bullets you suggest `\u25cf` are just bigger than mine `\u2022`. Nothing else. :)

Comment: I would separate the bullets and text into two separate TextViews. This will allow you to add a margin to the text so wrapping is consistently spaced. Each line would be a set of TextViews. You can add these to a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `BulletSpan` like this:

```
int leadingMargin = 16;
text.setSpan(new BulletSpan(leadingMargin), start, end, 0);
```

[reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BulletSpan.html)

Comment: Thanks - is it possible to do that in the xml?

Comment: @JoeBlow Unfortunately no.

Answer (score -1):

Just press abc ,
 then star/asterisk ,
Then, spacebar once - immediately after spacebar is pressed, the asterisk will change to a round bullet and become indented.

Comment: No idea in what environment or software this might work ...